# iOS: Launch AppStore page within my App

Tags: iphone, ios

I seen games like
Kingdom Clash
Castle Story

being able to launch AppStore within their game without minimizing their game.
The AppStore page will just slide in from bottom, show a game page, and players can download that game, key in their password, close the page and they are still in the game.

Is there a way to do this?
I can only minimize my own app, and open the Appstore.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SKStoreProductViewController class

Import StoreKit framework

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
```

Implement the SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate

```
@interface MyViewControllerClass : NSObject <SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate> {
}

- (void) openAppStore
{
    if( NSStringFromClass([SKStoreProductViewController class]) != nil )
    {
        SKStoreProductViewController *viewCont = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
        viewCont.delegate = self;
        [viewCont loadProductWithParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"APP_ID_FROM_ITUNES" forKey:SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier] completionBlock:nil];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:viewCont animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        // open safari
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8"]];
    }
}


// SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate
-(void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)productViewController
{
    [productViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is working fine for me.
But i have 2 problems, 
1) when I tap cancel in the AppStore, it crashes.

2) when I use iPad to play the iPhone game. The AppStore that is loaded in the viewer, will be iPad AppStore resolution, hence the most of the content will not be seen. So do I assume that iPad will not be able to load iphone Appstore even if the game is iphone game?

Please advise,

Comment: What does the crash log say? 2. You are right iPad can't load the iPhone appstore.